# Calculating the limit of $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n(x_n^2+3a)}{3x_n^2+a}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Let $x_{n+1}=\dfrac{x_n(x_n^2+3a)}{3x_n^2+a}$, where $x_1＞0,a＞0$. I guess the limit of $\{x_n\}$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is $\sqrt{a}$.

I tried to use the monotone bounded convergence theorem. If we let $f(x)=\dfrac{x(x^2+3a)}{3x^2+a}$ ,$f'(x)\leq 0$.How to check that the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is monotone? How to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=\sqrt{a}$?

Comment: What are your attempts at solving the problem?

Comment: I find that the sequence is not monotone, suppose $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, $f'(x)＜0$

Comment: In fact, we have $$f'(x) = \frac{3 (a-x^2)^2}{(a+3 x^2)^2} \geq 0,$$ so $f$ is non-decreasing. Now, it can be shown that if $I$ is an interval and $g : I \to I$ is continuous, non-decreasing, then $(g(x_n))_{n\geq 1}$ is monotone (but not necessarily increasing). Proving the general fact may require some work, but it shouldn't be hard for your particular case. As a hint, consider the cases $0<x_1<\sqrt{a}$ and $x_1>\sqrt{a}$ separately and use the the implications \begin{align*}0<x<\sqrt{a}&\quad\implies\quad0<x<f(x)<\sqrt{a},\\x>\sqrt{a}&\quad\implies\quad x>f(x)>\sqrt{a}.\end{align*}

Comment: According to your method, we know that $\{x_n\}$ has a lower bound or a upper bound, how to show that $(x_n)$  is monotone?

Comment: You may use induction :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First assume that $x_1\le \sqrt a$. Then $x_n\le \sqrt a$ for $n\ge 2$. In fact,
\begin{eqnarray}
x_{n+1}-\sqrt a=\dfrac{x_n(x_n^2+3a)}{3x_n^2+a}-\sqrt a=\dfrac{(x_n-\sqrt a)^3}{3x_n^2+a} \le0
\end{eqnarray}
by induction. Note
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}-1=\dfrac{x_n^2+3a}{3x_n^2+a}-1=\frac{2(a-x_n^2)}{3x_n^2+a}\ge0$$
and hence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded and increasing. So $\{x_n\}$ converges. You can treat $x_1>\sqrt a$ similarly.

Comment: But how to show that $(x_n)$ is increasing? As $f'(x)≥0$, we have $x_2=f(x_1)≤f(\sqrt{a})$, how to check that $x_2≥x_1$?

Comment: If $x_2\geq x_1$, we can show that the sequence is increasing.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way to derive the limit. To deal with sequences generated by repeat iterating some function. It is usually useful to look at fixed points of that function and construct auxiliary sequences based on those fixed points. Sometimes the recurrence relation of these auxiliary sequences will be simpler and allow you to derive what you want.

For the problem at hand, the function has $3$ fixed points at $0, \pm \sqrt{a}$.

Let $\alpha = \sqrt{a}$ and consider the auxiliary sequence
$$y_n = \frac{x_n - \alpha}{x_n + \alpha}\quad\iff\quad x_n = \alpha\frac{1+y_n}{1-y_n}$$ The sequence $y_n$ satisfies a signficantly simpler recurrence relation:

$$\begin{align}y_{n+1} &= \frac{x_{n+1} - \alpha}{x_{n+1} + \alpha}
= {\small \frac{\frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2)}{3x_n^2 + \alpha^2} - \alpha}{
\frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2)}{3x_n^2 + \alpha^2} + \alpha
}}
 = \small \frac{x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2)-\alpha(3x_n^2 + \alpha^2)}{
x_n(x_n^2 + 3\alpha^2)+\alpha(3x_n^2 + \alpha^2)}\\
&= \frac{(x_n-\alpha)^3}{(x_n+\alpha)^3}
= y_n^3\end{align}
$$

Solving this gives us

$$y_n = y_1^{3^{n-1}}\quad\implies\quad x_n = \alpha\frac{1 + y_1^{3^{n-1}}}{1 - y_1^{3^{n-1}}}$$

Since $x_1 > 0$, we have
$$|y_1| = \left|\frac{x_1 - \alpha}{x_1 + \alpha}\right| < 1 \implies 
\lim_{n\to\infty} y_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} y_1^{3^{n-1}} = 0$$
As a result,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\alpha\, \frac{1+y_n}{1-y_n} =
\alpha \, \frac{1+0}{1-0} = \alpha = \sqrt{a}$$